Estonian - typesettings (or catcode10)
I tried to adapt this solution for usage in my project. ONE of my problem is that when using estonian language the hyphens in the detect macro are not treated properly - i.e. they appear as squared box (instead as -)
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,estonian, naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,final]{microtype} % have some better layout of individual chars
\usepackage[shorthands=off]{babel}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
    "DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
    "NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
\babelfont{rm}%
[RawFeature={fallback=fntFallback},SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}% fonts for small caps
]{Liberation Sans}% Ligatures=TeX ist set automatically (used to have the automatics ligatures of TeX)
\usepackage{hyphenat} % allows hyphenation of compound words like 'Test- und Produktivszenarien' (see source code)

\def\linkText#1{\xscan#1\relax}% calls xscan which looks ahead one token, #1
\def\xscan{\afterassignment\xxscan\let\token= }% assign single token to \token and call \xxscan
\def\xxscan{%
    \ifx\token\relax\else%test for end-of-line or end of group and switch to ttfamily
    \ifcat\token\space%
    \token% token is catcode 10
    \spaceskip=.5em% remove glue from space for fixed-width space
    \xspaceskip=.5em% remove glue from space for fixed-width space
    \else%
    \token\hskip 0pt plus 1sp minus 1sp % add glue to any non-catcode 10 (space)
    \fi
    \spaceskip=0pt% reset space skip
    \expandafter\xscan% feed next token to \xscan, which is effectively a recursive call
    \fi} 


\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{test}
Kant ipsum test 1 (\hyperlink{l4194-c8833}{\linkText{AA 27\hyp{}10\hyp{}2023}}). 

\begin{itemize}
\item 
{\hypertarget{l4194-c8833}{}}XX - 
{\selectlanguage{naustrian}Test für Österreich}
(27\hyp{}10\hyp{}2023): 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

The code by itself works since the second appearance of the text renders - properly 
Remark: When I remove naustrian the code won't compile twice. I guess the issues are related. If not I'll ask separately.

the \xscan macros works with simple chars and spaces, but it doesn't like a command like \hyp. So don't use it for arbitrary input (that is quite independant from the language).

OK - thank you very much. I'll adapt the code.

Perhaps you could take a brief look as well to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/716194/48642 ? Similar issue but different result
